# Can't remove specific elements from array by index number from dynamic div element in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I can't remove specific elements of array by index number from any dynamic div

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Check(){
  var [Children, setChildren] = useState([])
    
  function RemArr(docs){
    const temp = [...Children]
    temp.splice(docs["i"], 1);
    setChildren(temp)
  } 
    
  function Product(docs) {
    var document = (<React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={()=>RemArr(docs)}>
        List {docs["i"]}
      </button>
      <p></p>
      <input/>
      <p></p>
    </React.Fragment>);
    setChildren([...Children, document])
  }

  return (<React.Fragment>
    <div>Check</div>
    {Children}
    <button
     onClick={()=>{Product({fix:false, i:Children.length})}}
    >Add List </button>
  </React.Fragment>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Check />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When i want to remove any specific div then not only this div remove from array, also remove next div from array.

Eg.

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If I want to remove only `6` from the array, however, it instead removes all the values from `6` to `9`, and so I am left with just:

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

I think the problem originates from this function:

```
function RemArr(docs){
  const temp = [...Children]
  temp.splice(docs["i"], 1);
  setChildren(temp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RemArr` function has a closure over `Children`, meaning that clicking on the remove button will call a potentially old declaration of `remArr`, where inside that `remArr`, the `Children` array will refer back to the Children array state from when you originally added the click event handler, rather than the current state of `Children`.

To overcome this, you can componentize `Product` rather than making it a function, and drive the `Children` based of some state in `Choice`, which you can use to generate your Product elements:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Product({docs, onClick}){
  return <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      List {docs.i}
    </button>
    <p></p>
    <input/>
    <p></p>
  </React.Fragment>;
}

function Check() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  function remArr(index){
    const temp = [...products];
    temp.splice(index, 1);
    setProducts(temp);
  }
  
  function addProduct() {
    const prevNum = products[products.length-1];
    setProducts([...products, {
      fix: false, 
      i: prevNum === undefined ? 0 : prevNum.i + 1
    }]);
  }

  return (<React.Fragment>
    <div>Check</div>
    {products.map(
      (doc, i) => <Product key={doc.i} docs={doc} onClick={() => remArr(i)}/>
    )}
    <button
     onClick={addProduct}
    >Add List</button>
  </React.Fragment>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Check />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The above `.map()` method that creates new `<Product />` components "updates"/re-sets the `onClick` function of all the product components to point to the "latest" declared `remArr` function, which has access to the correct/up to date `products` array. This is unlike your example, where the old JSX objects inside of the `Children` array still have `onClick` attributes that refer to the old declarations of the `remArr` function (which have access to the old `Children` array state)

Comment: I still do not get it. In OPs code remArr has access to the old Children. But shouldn't that be the case here too, remArr should have access to the old Products array?

Comment: @TusharShahi The `.map()` that creates new `<Product />` components "updates" the `onClick` function of all the components to point to the "latest" declared `remArr` function which has access to the correct/up to date `products` array.  Whereas in OPs code, the old JSX objects inside of the Children array still have `onClick` attributes that refer to the old declarations of the `remArr` function (which have access to the old `Children` array state)

Comment: Hey Nick Parsons Your code is working but not fully, Cause if i remove list 4 or any then its remove 4 number but my input isn't remove from 4 number field When click to remove it's always remove last input. & Also i need to initialize Product function inside main function (Check) cause i need to use useState which is define in Check function. So how to use Product function inside Check function? Please. & I'm using Next js

Comment: @MunnyReol hi, I've updated the `key` prop so that should fix the issue with the input. In terms of initializing Product inside of Check, that shouldn't ever need to be done. You can maintain your state in Check, and then pass through methods (such as setProducs) into the Product component using props, that will allow you to update the state of your Check component inside of Product

Comment: @NickParsons, Sorry Nick Parsons.. it's not working.
First i click 4 time on "Add List" button & then click 2 time on button "List 0" & "List 1" & then again click 1 time on "Add List" button... After that my "List 2" button isn't working.. How to fix this. Try yourself, it's error..

Comment: @MunnyReol you can change `i` so it's based on the previous list item's number plus 1. I've updated the snippet.