# Cannot access updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello Am i need of some assistance here am stuck,tried to serach for solution on SO but cant find a solution ,Am learning react so decided to create a todo app.However i have been stuck when it comes to crossing off completed tasks. when i add a task i have a variable called tasks which basically is an object containing all the tasks in the following fomart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbYwz.png)

Inside my app i have the following snippet of code

```
 const FILTER_MAP = {
  all_items:() => true,
  Active: task => !task.completed,
  Completed: task => task.completed
};

const FILTER_NAMES = Object.keys(FILTER_MAP);

function App(props) {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all_items');

  function addTask(name) {
    const newTask = {id: "todo-" + nanoid(),name: name, completed:false}
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  }

  function toggleTaskCompleted(id) {

    const updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => {
      // if this task has the same ID as the edited task
      if(id === task.id) {
      // use object spread to make a new object
      // whose `completed` prop has been inverted 
      return {...task,completed: !task.completed}
      }
      return task;
    })
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  }

  function clearCompletedTasks(){
     const completed = tasks.filter(task => task.completed === false)
     setTasks(completed);
  }
   
   const taskList = tasks
   .filter(FILTER_MAP[filter])
   .map(task => (
     <Todo 
       id={task.id} 
        name={task.name} 
        completed={task.completed}
        key={task.id}
        toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
        clearCompletedTasks={clearCompletedTasks}
     />
   ));

   const filterList = FILTER_NAMES.map(name => (
    <FilterButton 
      key={name} 
      name={name}
      isPressed={name === filter} 
      setFilter={setFilter}
    />
   ));
  
  const tasksNoun = taskList.length !== 1 ? 'items' : 'items';
  const headingText = `${taskList.length} ${tasksNoun} left`;

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
           <h1 id="pageTitle">Todo</h1>
         <div className="container">  
           <div className="main">
              <section className="tasklist"> 
                 <Form addTask={addTask}/>
                 <ul className="listItems">
                      <li className={`todo-item ${ tasks.completed ? "completed" :'' }`} >{taskList}</li>
                 </ul>
             </section> 
           </div> 
           <div className="footer">
            <div className="footer-list">
              <ul>
                  <li id="items">{headingText}</li>
                  <li id="all-items">{filterList[0]}</li>
                  <li id="active">{filterList[1]}</li>
                  <li id="completed">{filterList[2]}</li>
                  <li id="clear" onClick={clearCompletedTasks}>XClear Completed</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>  
      </header>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Todo**

```
export default function Todo(props){

     return (
         <li>
         <div className="todo">
            <label htmlFor={props.id}>
               {props.name}
            </label>
            <input id={props.id}
                type="checkbox"
                defaultChecked={props.completed}
                onChange={() => 
                 props.toggleTaskCompleted(props.id)}
            />
         </div>
      </li>
    );
}
```

**Problem**

When i click on checkbox to indicate the task is done i can see that the value in completed is updating to true as show below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsW0E.png)

However when i try to evaluate and apply the following css its not working.

```
<li className={`todo-item ${ tasks.completed ? "completed" :'' }`} >{taskList}</li>
```

How can i implement this so that "completed" style class is used when the state of completed value changes to true.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a const to store an array which gets changed.

The correct thing to do would be the following:

```
<ul>{tasks
   .filter(FILTER_MAP[filter])
   .map(task => (
     <li class={`todo-item ${ task.completed ? "completed" :'' }`}>
     <Todo 
       id={task.id} 
        name={task.name} 
        completed={task.completed}
        key={task.id}
        toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
        clearCompletedTasks={clearCompletedTasks}
     /></li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a case of stale state. When your function closes over an old state (think closures), then whenever called in future it has access to the old state itself. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236345/cant-remove-specific-elements-from-array-by-index-number-from-dynamic-div-eleme/68236617?noredirect=1#comment120599052_68236617)

Check if moving your {tasksList} code inside the return method helps:

```
 <li className={`todo-item ${ tasks.completed ? "completed" :'' }`} >{
tasks
   .filter(FILTER_MAP[filter])
   .map(task => (
     <Todo 
       id={task.id} 
        name={task.name} 
        completed={task.completed}
        key={task.id}
        toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
        clearCompletedTasks={clearCompletedTasks}
     />
   ));}</li>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tsushar Shahi,for your response,unfortunatley no luck,will try to revise and research more as i wait for some suggestions

Comment: Ok. Can you add more of your code? Where is the <ul> and probably more from your App.js where all of this logic lies.

Comment: done,hope thats helps.Thanks for your help